# React Router V4: how to programatically navigate to last visited page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Using react-router V4, how to programatically navigate to the last visited page ?

Does the code below sounds OK ?

```
this.props.history.push(this.props.history[this.props.history.length - 1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

`this.props.history.goBack();`

You can also use `go(n)`:

`this.props.history.go(-1);`

Check the [DOC](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation).

Comment: Easier than I thought... Thanks.